# Nested intervals proofs

Tags: real-analysis

> a. Let $I_n\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the open cells given by
>   $I_n=(0,1/n)\times \cdots\times (0,1/n)$. Show that these cells are
>   nested but that they do not contain any common point.
>
> b. let $J_n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the closed intervals given by
>   $J_n=[n,+\infty)\times \cdots\times [n,+\infty)$. Show that these
>   intervals are nested, but that they do not contain any common point.

I need to show for nested that $I_{n+1} \subset I_n$, for all $n$ correct? So, take $(x_1,\ldots,x_p) \in I_{n+1}$ Which means that every $x_i >0$ and $x_i< 1/(n+1)$, but I know that $1/(n+1) < 1/n$ so every $x_i$ it is also in $(0, 1/n)$, which means that is in the product $I_n$, correct? To show that there are no common points, I know that it is an open interval that when tend to infinity it will keep decreasing thus not having any common points; I am not sure if that is correct?

For b. I do not know how to do it for infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) Your argument to show that $I_{n+1}\subseteq I_n$ is correct. To show that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}I_n=\varnothing$, let $x=\langle x_1,\dots,x_p\rangle\in\Bbb R^p$ be arbitrary. If some $x_k\le 0$, then clearly $x\notin I_1$, so $x\notin\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}I_n$. If $x_k>0$ for $k=1,\dots,p$, let $a=\min\{x_1,\dots,x_p\}$, and choose $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ so that $\frac1n\le a$; clearly $x\notin I_n$. (You could actually set $a=\max\{x_1,\dots,x_p\}$, since you need only get $\frac1n$ less than or equal to **one** of the coordinates of $x$.)

(b) This really isn’t any different. If $x=\langle x_1,\dots,x_p\rangle\in I_{n+1}$, then $x_k\ge n+1$ for $k=1,\dots,x_p$, then clearly clearly $x_k\ge n$ for $k=1,\dots,p$, so $x\in I_n$, and therefore $I_n\supseteq I_{n+1}$. For any $x=\langle x_1,\dots,x_p\rangle$ we can let $a=\min\{x_1,\dots,x_p\}$ and choose a positive integer $n>a$; can $x$ possibly be in $I_n$?

**Added:** The picture below shows $I_2$ and $I_3$ in the case $p=2$; $I_2$ is the unbounded diagonally shaded region stretching off to the upper right, and $I_3$ is the similar cross-hatched region, also stretching off to the upper right, contained within it.

[image]

Comment: Hm, Brian, I don't quite understand the reasoning you introduced when you said, "If $x_k >0$  for $k=1,…,p$ , let $a=min\{x_1 ,…,x_p\}$, and choose $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ so that $1/n \le a$ ; clearly $x\notin I_n$"  ?

Comment: @Q.matin: If $\frac1n\le a$, then $x_1,\dots,x_p\ge a\ge\frac1n$, so $x_1,\dots,x_p\notin\left(0,\frac1n\right)$, and $x$ fails on every single coordinate to belong to $I_n$.

Comment: Since a = min what you are essentially showing is that there will always be some number smaller which then lead to the intervals not having a common element?

Comment: @Q.matin: I’m doing a bit more than that: for each $x\in\Bbb R^p$ I’m showing how to find an $I_n$ that does not contain that particular $x$. Since the recipe works for every $x\in\Bbb R^p$, no point of $\Bbb R^p$ is in all of $I_n$’s, and their intersection is therefore empty.

Comment: Still a bit confused, but I will keep re-reading it til I understand it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Q.matin: You’re welcome. If you have specific questions after you’ve thought about it for a while, feel free to ask.

Comment: Brian, for part b of this question I am a little confused. What you showed was that $x > n + 1 > n$, correct? If that is correct, then how will it be nested? Doesn't nested mean that $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$ which means that $x > n > n+1$, instead of $x > n + 1 > n$?

Comment: @Q.matin: No, I pointed out that **if** $x_k\ge n+1$ for $k=1,\dots,p$, i.e., if $x\in I_{n+1}$, **then** $x_k\ge n$ for $k=1,\dots,p$, i.e., $x\in I_n$. In other words, $I_{n+1}\subseteq I_n$. (Note that $x>n>n+1$ doesn’t make sense: $n$ is never greater than $n+1$.)

Comment: Hm, what I have difficulty understanding is why is it that $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$ instead of $I_{n} \subset I_{n+1}$? Since we concluded that $n+1>n$ wouldnt that make $I_{n} \subset I_{n+1}$?

Comment: @Q.matin: No, not at all. Look again at the definition of the sets $I_n$. Better yet, draw $I_2$ and $I_3$, say, when $p=1$ and $p=2$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still not understanding.

Comment: @Q.matin: Hold on a few minutes while I make and upload a picture.

Comment: @Q.matin: See if that picture helps.

Comment: Yes, it does help a lot; a bulb just hit my head, now I understand! Thank you very much, Brian!!

Comment: @Q.matin: Excellent! You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a different letter for the dimension; I shall use $d$.  Choose $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose $n > \max_{1\le k \le d} x_k$. Then $x\not\in J_n$. Hence $\cap_n J_n = \emptyset$.